# docker-compose up exited with code 1 because of few InnoDB errors

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have `cat orthomcl/Dockerfile`:

```
FROM debian:stretch-backports

RUN apt-get update  && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends \
        wget \
        cpanminus \
        build-essential \
        default-libmysqlclient-dev \
        python \
        ca-certificates \
        && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN mkdir diamond \
        && cd diamond \
        && wget -c https://github.com/bbuchfink/diamond/releases/download/v0.9.14/diamond-linux64.tar.gz \
        && tar xvf diamond-linux64.tar.gz \
        && rm *.tar.gz

RUN cpanm DBI DBD::mysql
RUN wget -c https://www.micans.org/mcl/src/mcl-latest.tar.gz
RUN tar xvf mcl-latest.tar.gz
RUN cd mcl-* && ./configure && make && make install
RUN wget -c https://orthomcl.org/common/downloads/software/v2.0/orthomclSoftware-v2.0.9.tar.gz
RUN tar xvf orthomclSoftware-v2.0.9.tar.gz

ENV PATH="/diamond:/orthomclSoftware-v2.0.9/bin:${PATH}"
```

This is my `docker-compose.yml`:

```
orthomcl:
    tty: true
    build: orthomcl
    restart: always
    links:
        - db
    volumes:
        - ./output_dir/:/output_dir

db:
  image: mysql
  restart: always
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=PAssw0rd
  ports:
    - "3306:3306"
  volumes:
    - ./mysql/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d
```

Next, I used `docker-compose up` which caused:

```
db_1        | 2019-05-02T23:59:03.981494Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
db_1        | 2019-05-02T23:59:03.981697Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.16) starting as process 1
db_1        | 2019-05-02T23:59:04.113140Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
db_1        | 2019-05-02T23:59:04.354244Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012530] [InnoDB] Unknown redo log format (103). Please follow the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ upgrading-downgrading.html.
db_1        | 2019-05-02T23:59:04.354289Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
db_1        | 2019-05-02T23:59:04.862813Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
db_1        | 2019-05-02T23:59:04.863115Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
db_1        | 2019-05-02T23:59:04.863285Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
db_1        | 2019-05-02T23:59:04.868499Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.16)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
db_1        | 2019-05-02T23:59:07.188586Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011070] [Server] 'Disabling symbolic links using --skip-symbolic-links (or equivalent) is the default. Consider not using this option as it' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release.
db_1        | 2019-05-02T23:59:07.188730Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.16) starting as process 1
db_1        | 2019-05-02T23:59:07.198834Z 1 [System] [MY-011012] [Server] Starting upgrade of data directory.
db_1        | 2019-05-02T23:59:07.310233Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012530] [InnoDB] Unknown redo log format (103). Please follow the instructions at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/ upgrading-downgrading.html.
db_1        | 2019-05-02T23:59:07.310273Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Generic error.
db_1        | 2019-05-02T23:59:07.826041Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011013] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine.
db_1        | 2019-05-02T23:59:07.826837Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
db_1        | 2019-05-02T23:59:07.829033Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
db_1        | 2019-05-02T23:59:07.835484Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.16)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
orthomcl_db_1 exited with code 1
```

How is it possible to solve the above InnoDB errors?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Was this an upgrade from an older version of MySQL?  Or a fresh install?